# Joomla update from 2.5.x to 3.x - Fatal error: Call to a member function IsAdmin() in remember plugin

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

The current joomla version is 2.5.22. However, client asked to update the joomla in 3.x. Therefore, I have used joomla update component to upgrade it in the upper version (3.x). But in the middle of this upgrading process a error has been triggered by the system which is actually like this:

Fatal error: Call to a member function isAdmin() on a non-object in E:\wamp\www\joomla\plugins\system\remember\remember.php on line 42

Comment: Try disabling the remember me plugin before updating. Have you or the client edited any of the core Joomla core files?

Answer (score 1):

The "Remember Me" plugin issue is well documented when updating Joomla to the latest version. You can read more about it here: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=32568

Some say that just disabling the "Remember Me" plugin works, others say that more needs to be done (disabling the "Remember Me" plugin worked for us all the time). You might want to check the bug listing on joomlacode if just disabling the plugin did not work for you.